# Why are not all the Bars in my Barchart red?

Tags: jfreechart, histogram

Somehow i am getting some white Bars into my Histogram, any idea why?

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3811/aybobuxf_png.htm

```
int number = 155897;//max number of Pixels   
HistogramDataset dataset = new HistogramDataset(); //create a Histogram   
dataset.setType(HistogramType.RELATIVE_FREQUENCY);     
dataset.addSeries("Histogram",doubleArray,number);     
String plotTitle = "Histogram";    
String xaxis = "pixel";     
String yaxis = "intensity";     
PlotOrientation orientation = PlotOrientation.VERTICAL;//sets the vertical orientation of the Histogram       
boolean show = false;      
boolean toolTips = false;     
boolean urls = false;     
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createHistogram( plotTitle, xaxis, yaxis,
dataset, orientation, show, toolTips, urls);    
int widthg = 500;     
int heightg = 300;     
try {     
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("histogram41.PNG"), chart, widthg, heightg);      
} catch (IOException e) {}    
}}
```

Comment: You've only got one series in your dataset.

Comment: i am adding a [][]doubleArray  //                             double[][] array = new double[100][100];    

    for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {     
       for ( int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length ; j++ ) {     
          array[i][j] = random.nextInt(256);    
       }   
    }

Comment: why is there a thin white line at the left side of evry bar, i need the bar to have only one colour

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117105).